# Get a list of required tags for site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, api-v2, tags

How can I get the tags which are required, (fulfills_required = true) for each site?

Like order/filter the tags route to show the fulfills_required tags first?

Comment: there is now the https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags method but i cannot get it to return any results.

Comment: Have you been using it against stackoverflow? Because it doesn't have any required tags :)

Comment: lol. borg mind at work. i just finished changing to stackapps and got some. here - let me answer your question for you ;-)

Comment: Since this is now a part of v2.0 of the API, I am marking this as [status-completed].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the original question was apparently for V1.

in V2 we now have https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags

the request: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags/required?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackapps will return required tags